# How pointers to out-of-scope-variable behave in C?

Tags: c, pointers, printf

I need to analyze the output of the following program:

```
#include "stdio.h"
void foo(int **const p)
{
    int j = 11;
    *p = &j;
    printf("%d ", **p);
}
int main()
{
    int i = 10;
    int *p = &i;
    foo(&p);
    printf("%d ", *p);
    printf("%d ", *p);
}
```

I know nobody actually writes this way, but nonetheless. I expected it to output something like `11 [garbage] [garbage]`, only to find the answer is `11 11 [undefined value]`. I decided to spin a bit.

```
#include "stdio.h"
void foo(int **p)
{
    int j = 11;
    *p = &j;
    printf("1:-");
    printf("%d-", **p);
}
int main()
{
    int i = 10;
    int *p = &i;
    foo(&p);
    /* printf("2:-"); */ 
    printf("%d-", *p);
    printf("3:-");
    printf("%d-", *p);
}
```

This would give `1:-11-11-3:-0-` on my platform (macOS 10.12.2, tested both on Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1) and Homebrew gcc 6.2.0).

And if I un-comment that `printf("2:-");` line I would get `1:-11-2:-0-3:-0-`. The second call prints `p` differently. Again both compilers yield same result.

Here are my questions:

1. Is the original answer even correct? And how is it (in)correct?
2. Why and how does that commented call to `printf` changes the content of `p`? Or am I missing the point?

Comment: "11" is a legal value for "garbage".

Comment: Dereferencing a pointer to data that no longer "exists" leads to *undefined behavior*. It *might* seem to work, or it might crash, or it might lead to [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

Comment: The behavior of the program is undefined due to access to an object after the end of its lifetime.

Comment: Analyzing the *undefined behavior* is a useless task in most cases.

Comment: @RaymondChen When voting to close as a dup, please observe the language tag.

Answer (score 1):

The pointer's value is indeterminate and referring to that object invokes undefined behavior, according to *6.2.4p2 Storage durations of objects*:

> [...] If an object is referred to outside of its lifetime, the behavior is undefined. The value of a pointer becomes indeterminate when the object it points to reaches the end of its lifetime.